# install bundler using rvm, ruby 1.8.7 with gcc 4.7 on linux

Tags: ruby, linux, gcc, rvm, bundler

Issues building ruby 1.8.7 or installing the bundler gem with GCC 4.7 on linux (Fedora 17, Arch, etc.).  This issue occurred for me using RVM.  I was able to install 1.8.7, but unable to install the bundler gem.  I would receive the following error:

```
$ gem install bundler

~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:60: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [x86_64-linux]
```

this issue is described in a number of locations, including:

- [ruby-enterprise 1.8.7-12: timeout.rb:60: [BUG] Segmentation fault](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=139573)
- [Ruby gem install is seg faulting](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=139547)
- [rvm install rbx fails on archlinux (mri 1.8 + gcc 4.7 issue)](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/959)
- [ruby1.8: segfaults when compiled with gcc-4.7](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=674541)
- [Ruby 1.8.7 fails to build (Arch Linux, gcc > 4.6)](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/issues/147)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The description of the problem in the links in the original question suggest installing older versions of gcc to build 1.8.7, **this is not necessary**.

```
$ rvm remove 1.8.7
$ CFLAGS="-O2 -fno-tree-dce -fno-optimize-sibling-calls" rvm install 1.8.7
$ rvm use 1.8.7
$ gem install bundler
```

Solution derived from the following:

[Bug #6383: Segfault in Timeout module when compiled with GCC 4.7](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6383#note-1)

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me using:
OS X 10.7.4

Answer (score 1):

Also, I would ensure that you have the stable release that was released as of today, May 30, 2012 which is 4.7.0 and NOT one of the previous 4.7 releases which were not stable releases. RVM has a policy of not supporting non-stable-releases (aka development versions) of GCC for the reason that, well we're not compiler guys hehe.

Then, in addition, please uninstall and reinstall your original version of 1.8.7. Another option is to 'rvm reinstall 1.8.7' though not all previous configure options may be regenerated to include acceptance of the changed CFLAGS variable, as written to the config. @mpapis, do we need to advocate use of the --autoconf --force here?

(mpapis and I are devs on the RVM Project so this is as good a place as any to discuss flags and monitor to see which should be done so we can push the info to anyone else that comes to us about this)

Comment: I've seen the `-O2` fix somewhere already, I guess for older rubies, we can extend for GCC47 on any 1.8 ruby. as for compilers not marked as stable - I would assume they could fail and any errors/issues should be reported first to compiler development team.

Comment: yeah definitely not going to support non-stable releases of compiler chains. There be dragons there. We'll leave that for the guys actually good with compiler guts. What would be nice though is if, along the way, we could find out optimal compiler options for each Ruby Major.Minor version that wouldn't introduce 'hidden' problems. (-funroll -loops back in the day anyone? hehe). Something like that would probably be of use to document as time goes by on the RVM FAQ page. Any Ruby devs monitoring want to chime in?