# Failed to configure Ruby with RVM on Fedora15

Tags: ruby, installation, rvm

I run `rvm install 1.9.3` to update Ruby on my Fedora 15.
But it failed and showed the message:

```
    checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... no
    checking for working volatile... yes
    configure: error: ANSI C-conforming const and volatile are mandatory
```

Searched all over but cant find a solution.
Anyone could help? thx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot run rvm to install any version of ruby with gcc-4.6.3.
Finally get it resolved via suggestion in the post:
[install bundler using rvm, ruby 1.8.7 with gcc 4.7 on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820323/install-bundler-using-rvm-ruby-1-8-7-with-gcc-4-7-on-linux/11496911#11496911)

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed all required dependencies? If not, run `rvm notes`  and then install the required packages.

Comment: Yes, I have already installed all required dependencies. Except for iconv-devel, only shows  `No package iconv-devel available` . Instead I groupinstalled all the development tools. Still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error when installing in linux. Turns out it was because i added the `--64` option which may be for [MAC only](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/639). When I removed that flag, that error message was gone.